# What are some of the better Windows 7 Themes?

Tags: windows-7, themes

I'm mostly looking for good desktop backgrounds here. 
Themes as in Windows 7 Theme Packs.

Comment: Similar: http://superuser.com/questions/10775/good-website-for-wallpapers

Comment: That's just for wallpapers. I think he's looking for a more comprehensive theming.

Comment: "I'm mostly looking for good desktop backgrounds here."

Comment: @musicfeak: That's a recent edit, I think. It didn't say that when I was replying... :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offhand, i would say:

- [Mark Swanson's themes](http://blogs.msdn.com/mswanson/archive/2009/01/25/my-windows-7-theme-pack.aspx)
- [some Windows7News themepacks](http://windows7news.com/2009/01/12/windows-7-theme-packs/)
- [an IntoWindows page with a bunch](http://www.intowindows.com/download-14-awesome-windows-7-themes/)
- [Windows7Themes.Net](http://windows7themes.net/)
- [My humble themepack](http://www.mediafire.com/?mmcjmhzzyy4) (Made by me, nothing too spectacular but nice if you like nebula-ish fractal-y backgrounds, rendered by apophysis) (NOTE: NO WARRANTY IS EXPRESS OR IMPLIED BY POSTING THIS LINK yadda yadda yadda... Don't blame me if your computer blows up.)

and, of course, the great grandaddy of them all:

- http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/personalize

Comment: the ones you made are awesome. they're now my new theme. thanks

Answer (score 2):

**[Windows 7 News](http://windows7news.com/windows-7-theme/)** has a nice collection of themes for Windows 7.

There are 2 categories:

- [Official Windows 7 Themes](http://windows7news.com/windows-7-theme/official-windows-7-themes/)
- [Unofficial Windows 7 Themes](http://windows7news.com/windows-7-theme/unofficial-windows-7-themes/)

A patch is needed to install the unofficial themes, like [UxStyle](http://uxstyle.com/) for instance.

Comment: Plus one for UxStyle. This is FAR AND AWAY the best "patching" solution out there for running unofficial themes, as it does NOT actually require PATCHING the system, and doesn't affect system files, and can be installed/uninstalled with a standard installer program.

Comment: I would not recommend using any sort of patching to apply non-official themes, unless you *really* know what you're doing. Now that W7 has a halfway-decent theming system, it's not half as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In case you mean more than just "wallpapers" when you say "themes", you should know that [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com) frequently posts awesome themes for all operating systems. I'll post a few for Windows 7 that I can find (I'll keep editing this post over the next few minutes as I find more)

- http://lifehacker.com/5170413/the-windows-2019-desktop
- http://lifehacker.com/5158878/
- http://lifehacker.com/5288658/the-starlight-desktop
- http://lifehacker.com/5297193/the-halo-3-hud-desktop
- http://lifehacker.com/5161303/the-stars-memory-desktop
- http://lifehacker.com/5402431/the-gaia-desktop

And in case you're experiencing some Apple envy, here's one that OS X-ifies Windows:

- http://lifehacker.com/5428018/the-mac+like-windows-desktop

Comment: These are desktop makeovers. I'm talking about Windows 7 theme packages